# What was the last landmass on Earth to be settled by human beings?

Tags: world

As the abstract of [this article](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/early/2012/03/15/rspb.2012.0012.full) claims,

> Madagascar was one of the last landmasses to be reached by people ... Madagascar was settled approximately 1200 years ago by a very small group of women (approx. 30), most of Indonesian descent (approx. 93%).

So is Madagascar the most-recently settled landmass in the world?

(I do not know what a good definition of "settle" is, but I might suggest this: Multiple generations living and reproducing continuously. This is to exclude places like Antarctica.)

Comment: See [Dewar, et al. "Stone tools and foraging in northern Madagascar challenge Holocene extinction models." *PNAS*, 110.31 (2013)](http://www.pnas.org/content/110/31/12583.short) for a newer and opposing point of view regarding Madagascar's late settlement.

Comment: 1. What do you mean under landmass? How big it should be? Are small islands counted? 2. Should it be an island, or may be peninsula, desert, steppe, plateu etc? 3. What do you mean under "exclude places like Antarctica"?

Comment: I strongly disagree with the hold. Timelines of human settlement are a very important area of interest to historians and archaeologists.

Comment: Antarctica.  no doubt about it.

Comment: The last place of settlement was Atlantis

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[New Zealand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Zealand#History) is usually credited to be the last significant area on Earth to have been colonized by human beings in the sense of the question; as the first settlers seem to have arrived in the late 1200CE. By contrast, there are signs of human settlements on Madagascar dating from the beginning of the common era and records of trade with the island dating from around 700CE, so half a millennia before anyone stepped foot on New-Zealand (and indeed, even Iceland seems to have been colonized much later than Madagascar).